# Sharing something in Social Media in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, share

I want to implement a share option in my app which will allow user to share something or say post something to his linked account(like facebook, twitter, linkedin etc). But i am not getting any clue. I read somewhere that in WindowsPhoneTool71 the share property is inbuilt, but I am using WindowsPhoneTool7. So anybody out there to help me out.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using WP7 rather than WP7.1? The Mango release was rolled out months ago, so you can guarantee that any Windows Phone 7 user will certainly have had the update by now. With Windows Phone 7.1 the ShareStatusTask will do exactly what you want in just lines of code!

```
ShareStatusTask task = new ShareStatusTask();
task.Status = "User Status";
task.Show();
```

Comment: you still have not stated why WP7? If you can give a valid reason, I might be able to help!

Comment: i've to provide this app to a vendor who wants app for WP7. He is not ready to upgrade and I am not able to convince him for that.. So can you help me out.